# CCSprite Frame Changing Programmatic Error

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

```
CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]
                        spriteFrameByName:@"grossini_dance_02.png"];
[_hero setDisplayFrame:frame]
```

Using the above code, however receiving the following error.

```
No visible @interface for 'CCSprite' declares the selector 'setDisplayFrame:'
```

Has anyone else encounter this error, and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: works for me ... what version of cocos are using ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I'm not too sure, if it helps I'm using SpriteBuilder to create my project, so whatever version is utilized by that program.

Answer (score 0):

To change the frame of a sprite in cocos2d ver.3 write

```
self.spriteFrame = frame;
```

I don't think setDisplayFrame or displayFrame are in cocos2d ver.3.